# Google Form is not displaying full form on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Problem:** My Google form is cut off on mobile phones. End users are having a difficult time understanding the iframe is scrollable.

**What I have tried:** I have been searching online for ideas. I tried height: 1000px and height: 100% both with no luck.

**Goal of this post:** I am hoping someone can show me how to display the full length of the Google form without compromising the responsiveness of the site.

I have added a screenshot of what I see on my phone.

[image]

```css
#headerText {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    padding-top: .7%;
}

.img-fluid {

    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.bg {
    background: url(https://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/kindajean.png);
    width: auto;
}

.boxWhite {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.text-primary {

    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

}

#googleForm {
    height: 1000px;
}

.button {
    padding: 30px 0 80px 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

}

.seanText {
    background: white;
    color: #007BFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 1.2px;
    padding: 20px 10% 20px 10%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.iframe {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

#header {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #007BFF;
    height: 120px;
    padding-top: 2%;

}

.iframeSean {

    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Sean Is Getting Married</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerText">
            <a href="http://seanisgettingmarried.com" class="text-center bg-primary text-white headerText">Sean Brown's
                Bachelor Party</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 iframe">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item iframeSean"
                src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScQ2hk1LN-1ZY1s9hmltqaIx5p8NSHJyE1-1mz-HSJ-sDMDGg/viewform?embedded=true"
                width="640" height="1103" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"> Loading…</iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you don't specify height and width for the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

**Increase the Height:**

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item iframeSean"
                src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScQ2hk1LN-1ZY1s9hmltqaIx5p8NSHJyE1-1mz-HSJ-sDMDGg/viewform?embedded=true"
                width="640" **height="2500"** frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"> Loading…</iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @minhaz ahmed, welcome to stack overflow!  Nice first answer, but it would be great if you could provide more context around what the issue is and what changes you've made to make it more clear to users when they are reading your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Change width to 100% and height to 500px**

Loading…

Answer (score 0):

first of all, get rid of the width and height default values in the html code.
Assign a class to the iframe, something like: class="responsive-iframe".
Next, add the following CSS:

`.responsive-iframe { width: 100vw;  height: 100vh; }`

Since 100% didn't work for me, this method worked perfect on Desktop and mobile.
Cheers.